# I have installed XAMPP on my mac mini i get only XAMPP.app file but unable to find XAMPP folder where should i put php files

Tags: php, mysql, macos, xampp

This is screenshot of Applications folder. There is only XAMPP.app file but not XAMPP folder.

[image]

Comment: mac gives apache server with php by default, will not need to install xampp

Comment: but in my pc there is no any XAMPP folder, may be its deleted but how do i get that ?? @ÁlvaroTouzón

Comment: only apache no xampp...

Comment: Ok, but i want xampp folder

Comment: you need to search httpd or www folder